# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's really neat! Kudos to Yi Jiang.

Could there be the badge descriptions on the page as well? I mean, the names aren't as cryptic as something like an Xbox Live Achievement, but I still had to go and look to see what 'Sportsmanship' was.

And could there be a possibility for it to be linked to the election page?

Comment: Your first concern has been updated - hovering over the badges will now produce a tooltip that explains what the badge is.